# fluid css but no smaller than a fixed-width

Tags: css, fluid, fluid-layout, fixed-width

Okay I am looking into fluid css for a map aspect I need to implement on my site.  I found this demo that looked like what I wanted:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-39-fluid-fluid-fluid/

Is there a way to make the left column and right column be fluid so they can expand with larger browser windows.  But not be able to restrict below a certain width, say 175px each?

So, if there is more browser space for some users, I want to be able to use it, thus allowing all three columns to be fluid.  But the right and left column can't go below a certain width no matter how small the browser window is (excluding mobile browsers, not a mobile app).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the following tag on the element(s) you want to shrink but go no smaller than 175px;

```
min-width: 175px;
```

now this is only compliant with IE8 and above IE7 does support it kind of, but it can be a little buggy so you need to be careful using it

it is fully supported by firefox 3.6+ (maybe earlier), safari, and opera 10+

Comment: I tried that after I posted this question and it kind of works, but it kind of doesn't.  I'm aware of the IE issues.

look at the demo I got up: http://fuudhub.com/demo/fluid.html

I added the min-width element but the right column, gold one, padding starts to mess up because of the way it determines it:

`code`
#rightcolumn{
margin: 0 62% 0 15%; /*Margins for right column. Should be "0 contentcolumnWidth 0 rightcolumnWidth*/
background: #FDE95E;
min-width: 223px;
}
`code`

Comment: @thindery have you got a jsfiddle.net on it or something to explain what's not working?

Comment: I made a number of changes too many to detail but here is the jsfiddle with the updates so that it works http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Efs/4/

Comment: hey thanks for looking into it.  I see what you did, but the divs are out of alignment now.  they are suppose to be more like this: 

http://fuudhub.com/demo/fluid.html  

with the left column and right column (green and gold) to have the min width.  if you look at the demo in the browser the gold div is getting pushed behind the green div.

It's because the padding issue.  I need something like min-padding on the gold div so it doesn't get pushed below the green one.  But min-padding isn't supported in css.

Comment: thindery that's just a matter of moving the right column block.  http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Efs/5/

Comment: Wow. Thanks man. I see you did change a bit. You make it look easy.